# DataGridView CurrentRow Cell Value=null but it doesnt

Tags: c#, datagridview

I had problem with this codes:

```
cell_0_value= dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

It says null at dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value but my table has 6 column and it already has value.

How do i get over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `CurrentRow` you must have a cell selected first. Otherwise, `CurrentRow` returns null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: No my datagridview.CurrentRow is not null because Datagridview.CurrentRow.Count >0 but ...Cells[0].Value says null

Comment: Why don't post the exact exception that you get. "says null" doesn't help at all.

Comment: And when exception occur my datagridview has "currentrow sign ►"

Comment: I want to change Datatype of Datatable's column and i try create all datatable columns in datagridview. And when i fill data to datagridview it display ok but above code doest work again

Comment: You can't change the datatype of columns once there's data in the columns. Without the complete exception no one can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I have solved my problem with another way.